# Testing - Relative path for sources

Tags: l3build, packages-testing

I would like to use the following structure to code and test my package. **The folder is built automatically from a source folder not designed to be distributed.** This is my workflow.

```
.
├── README.md
├── bdoc
│   ├── bdoc-FR.pdf
│   ├── bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty
│   ├── bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty
│   └── bdoc.sty
└── tests
    ├── build.lua
    └── testfiles
        └── write-macro-n-pack.lvt
```

How can I tell to `l3build` to look for my source code in the up folder `bdoc` ?

For the moment, my `build.lua` is minimalist... And not functional yet.

```lua
module = "bdoc"

sourcefiles={"*.sty"}
```

If it is not possible, I would to know if even for complex use cases, only the file `build.lua` can be used to work with `l3build`?

Comment: why just build.lua in tests? you don't plan to use it to build the sources or package releases?

Comment: Yes I want but I would like to keep the source inside one single folder. If it is not possible, I will follow `l3build`...

Comment: you can do it, just seems strange to have build.lua in the test dir, I'd have it one level up, or in the source directory but I think it should just work as you have it if you set sourcefiles={"../bdoc/*"}

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Sorry for my question. I will adapt my automated tools to put things inside the same folder as `build.lua`... I fail to launch `l3build`, and if expert points the weirdness of my point of view, I have to look at the good direction... :-) Thanks for all.

Comment: This gives me `Running checks on
  write-macro-n-pack (1/1)
Error: failed to find any reference or expectation file for write-macro-n-pack!`

Comment: `l3build save ...` gives `LaTeX Error: File 'bdoc.sty' not found.` I will conform with standard. I will change my automated tools to be more prudent when updating final code.

Comment: even if you specify ../bdoc/*.sty as source files? (I suppose I could build a test example to try, but it seems you should provide that:-)

Comment: Here is my toy code : https://github.com/bc-tools/for-latex/tree/dev /: the `bdoc` folder has a POC folder for this question. Please do not laugh... ;-) I am working on my workflow, and then I will try to give useful packages and classes to the community.

Comment: I cleaned up some comments. The directory structure is a bit weird, but I'm not sure why setting checksuppfiles  to ../bdoc/*.sty isn't making them available I may look another day, too late now,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure is rather strange, as `build.lua` is intended as the entry point to the *build* pipeline so `build.lua` is normally at the root of the original source tree but your comment says this is part of a generated structure.

However this does appear to work

if `tests/build.lua` is

```
module = "bdoc"

maindir=".."
supportdir= maindir .. "/bdoc"
testsuppdir= supportdir
testfildir= maindir .. "/tests"
```

then

```
cd tests
l3build save write-macro-n-pack
```

will write a normalised reference result to `write-macro-n-pack.tlg`  and then

```
l3build check write-macro-n-pack
```

Will report:

```
  Check failed with difference files
  - ../build/test/write-macro-n-pack.luatex.diff
  - ../build/test/write-macro-n-pack.xetex.diff
```

as the luatex and xetex log output is different in this case. So you would need to save `.luatex.tlg` and `.xetex.tlg` versions as well (or adjust the test file to log data that is not engine specific).

Comment: I have one last problem. The command `l3build ctan` produces an empty `zip`. On the other hand, `l3build manifest` works as expected.

Comment: I added bdoc to the support dir so it is copied for tests but you probably also need to add it to source files and similar directories. Really putting build.lua in a more normal place would be easier, if you really want this I may try later, just need to check exactly which variables to set. But running l3build check in teh test dir is sort of reasonable if you are just using l3build for testing. having it in the test directory for building the release is very very weird. @projetmbc

Comment: You are totally right, I will use the standard way because this produces more problems than simplifications. Your answer remains still interesting as an example of use of some global variables.